# How would export templates be implemented?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, c++98

Export templates are a feature in pre-2011 C++ where the implementation of a template would be deferred to a separate source file.

[According to this article](http://warp.povusers.org/programming/export_templates.html), it's possible to write "manual" export templates via manually specifying for each type used in the implementation file. Since this would simply create specific symbols - I believe in a similar fashion to overloaded functions - it makes sense how this would be implemented.

But it's my understanding that an exported template (via the `export` keyword) is arbitrary. It can allow any type of data to be passed.

Take this simple example:

```
template<typename T>
T add(T value1, T value2) {
    return value1 + value2;
}
```

The assembly output for this example would differ wildly if T was an `int`, a `float`, or especially an `std::string` (and any other type that overloads the `+` operator).

Since it's completely arbitrary, how would a compiler implement this keyword?

My guess is code generation at link time, which would most likely require a custom object file format, containing some representation of the code. But this makes the linker a compiler as well, which breaks the preprocesser-compiler-linker separation.

Answer (score 1):

Around 2001, EDG implemented `export`, and Comeau provided me with an early build. I was indeed capable of instantiating `A<B<A<B<A<int> > > > >` where `A<T>` was defined in A.cpp and `B<T>` was defined in B.cpp. Obviously, that requires some form of link-time code generation.

This was even more amazing because Comeau actually used MSVC as a back-end, while Microsoft at the same time was arguing that this was impossible! (This was why I was evaluating `export` in the first place, WG21 paper N1426)

Answer (score 0):

templated things are only instantiated to the concrete types when they are referred to by the code being compiled.

At that point the compiler needs all the information (structure definitions, function definitions) in order to generate the code.

If the only definition the compiler sees when importing a structure  is

```
  export templat< ... > class foo;
```

It has no mechanism to generate the code and fails when features of class foo are requested.

Conversely when a library is being built the definition and implementation are all available to the compiler, but it can't see which types may be used by the library.

The only (needed?) mechanism available, is a header file.  This has the definition and implementation, and avoids the need for a special object format.

If you explicitly instantiate concrete examples of your template, these can be exported from a library, but only for pre-known types.

Answer (score 0):

There is a myth that exported templates were expected by some people to be strictly separately compiler, but no evidence that any of those people (if they existed) were committee members.

Exported templates are indeed normal templates with ordinary template semantics. (They are not similar O'Caml or Haskell modules.)

Separate compilation that produces binary code is *based on an ABI*. It wouldn't make sense to make an ABI for templates of functions (as opposed to their instantiations).

**Templates in C++ are essentially macro-like**. Not crappy C/C++ preprocessor macro likes, which are token based and thus disregard the C or C++ grammar structure, but they were very close to substitution based (at the grammatical entity not lexer lever).

They tend to pull **a lot** of names from the instantiation context, more then we would want. That's because there is no way to have a "concept" meta type system in C++. (And C++ is too complex and much too irregular to retrofit such a thing.)

Without a "concept" contract for C++ templates, the C++ language definition can't strictly limit the names that might be looked-up in the instantiation context: even something as obvious as `a<b` isn't by definition a boolean value in C++. It's by convention a boolean represented by a normal boolean type (`bool` or `int`) but it could be anything (there are use cases for making the return type a class type).

So even something like `f(a<b)` in a template might need to pull `f` from the context of instantiation, unlike `f(bool(a<b))`.

**Obviously true separate compilation of templates is not possible.** That was never the intent of exported templates.

Templates are instantiated based on both the template definition context and the point of instantiation context; if the template is not a header file, it just means that the compiler will consider two source files. As such it isn't even a serious difficulty. (There are certainly difficult issues, but dealing with multiple source files isn't one.)

Of course it implies that "linking" of C++ code will not be normal linking: it will involve running the compiler again for each template instantiation needed, until all instantiations are done.

(And "runtime linking" would not include such template-instantiation-linking and wouldn't be allowed to call the compiler to create code.)

**Everything I mentioned here was clear and obvious at the time.** There is zero evidence that any person who seriously contributed to the design of the language ever had a different intuition.

In fact, **originally C++ only had exported template, so much that it didn't have an `export` keyword**.